# Conventions for Klein factors in bosonization of Quantum Hall edge states

Tags: topological-field-theory, topological-order, quantum-hall-effect

I am not having much experience in the field of bosonization, hence the following question:

In some papers (such as https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9501007 Eq. (6) )
a Quantum Hall edge is bosonized by introducing the equal time commutation relations
$
\left[ \Phi_{i}(x) , \Phi_{j}(x')\right] = i \pi \left( K_{ij} sgn(x-x') + L_{ij}\right)
$
with $K_{ij}$ being the $n\times n$ K-matrix describing the Quantum Hall phase and
$L_{ij}=sgn(i-j)\left(K_{ij}-Q_{i}Q_{j}\right)$ being the Klein factors and
$Q_{i}$ being some n-dimensinal charge vector.

Still other papers (such as https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.3989 Eq.(A2) )
use $
\left[ \Phi_{i}(x) , \Phi_{j}(x')\right] = -i \pi \left( K_{ij}^{-1} sgn(x-x') + \theta_{ij}\right)
$ with $\theta_{ij}=K_{ik}^{-1}L_{kl}K_{lj}^{-1}$ and $L_{ij}$ as before.

Now there seems to be both a change in an overall minus-sign as well as a
"conjugation" of the Klein factors by the inverse K-matrix.

I am wondering why these two descriptions are equivalent?

Comment: You have an error in your first formula, it is $K_{ij}$ and not $K^{-1}_{ij}$. With a transformation $\Phi_i(x) \to  \Phi'_i(x) = iK^{-1}_{ik}\Phi_k(x)$ (with $K^{-1}$ symmetric), we could  go approximatively from the first equation to the second...

Comment: Questions edited. Thanks for the reply. But don't we need a transformation among the field thats unitary?